# extension news typo3 preview function

Tags: typo3, tx-news

Hi I am looking for a way to preview a new newspost with the extension news from Georg Ringer. Is there a way or an extension to do this? In the documentation I cannot find a way to achieve this. Does anybody has a workaround for this?

Comment: What about creating the plugin element on a hidden page and view it as an admin in the frontend?

Comment: This sounds Mike an idea but if you have somebody who does not understand that you habe two pages for a news this is quiete complicated for him. I was thinking about a feature if he is logged in in the backend he can see only a specific category or all hidden news are visible at that time. I am not quiete shure if this is a workaround in that case.

Comment: Please enable a spell checker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Michael says, you need to create a (hidden = BE users only) preview page with a news plugin on it and set

```
plugin.tx_news.settings.enablePreviewOfHiddenRecords =1
```

See http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/Configuration/TypoScript/Index.html?highlight=hidden#previewhiddenrecords

If you call this page something "preview page for hidden news", it should be very understandable for editors.

Comment: This is what I have been looking for. I will check with a condition if the user is logged in in the backend and then he can preview everything. Thank you very much.

Comment: you don't need to add a condition if the page is hidden - BE users can see all hidden pages displayed with a red "PREVIEW" button

Comment: If this condition is triggered for BE user that´s great. I thought this only works for pages not for records like newsrecords.

Comment: The page with the plugin that (thanks to that setting) shows the hidden news items is hidden. So if someone (like a BE user) can see that hidden page, he can see the hidden records too.

Comment: Not fully. In the list view the records are not shown. You have to go to the detailpage in the backend and explicitly open the newsrecord. This helps me a little bit, but what can I do to see this record in the list view, when this newsrecord is hidden? And when I am editing this news I cannot save and preview this record because the wrong link is triggered. I have to go to the detailpage and open the specific newsrecords.

Comment: you may need the tsconfig setting "tx_news.singlePid = {pid of page with newsdetail}" too.

Comment: You can use the admin panel in the Frontend to render hidden records. This should do it!